# Is it true that all verbs have a corresponding noun form?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

Is it true that all verbs have a corresponding noun form (which is formed by making the -masu form and removing the -masu)?

Like 遊び and 遊びます
飲み and 飲みます
生き and 生きます
死に and 死にます

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the most part, yes. There are a few outliers that don't though. Most 尊敬語 and 謙譲語 verbs don't form nouns with their 連用形. And some 連用形, such as 「なり」, are specialized almost to the point of uselessness.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that most 尊敬語 and 謙譲語 verbs do not have 連用形.  They always have 連用形, but their 連用形 are rarely used as nouns.

Comment: Fair enough. I will correct that part then.

Comment: heys thanks for the answer =P btw i'd just realised the -masu form of 食べる without the ます (i.e. 食べ) is not a word?

Comment: @Pacerier: Sure, that's another outlier. But 「見」, 「寝」, and 「居」 are all nouns, so it's not a 一段 vs. 五段 thing.

Comment: @Ignacio ok thx, btw just curious.. if 食べ is not the noun form of 食べる then what is the noun form of 食べる ?

Comment: @Pacerier: There isn't one. Use 「食」 or 「食べ物」 as appropriate.

Comment: @Ignacio ok got it =D

Comment: So if I follow this correctly, 食べ is the 連用形 of 食べる, but it is not used as a noun. What uses then does 食べ have?

Comment: @hippietrail: Same as every other 連用形, e.g. 「食べ過ぎる」, etc.