# proper usage of 出かける

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, etymology

What is the proper usage of 出かける because most of the time I am only using 行く or 出る

for example 川へせんたくしに行く and I don't get its difference from 川へせんたくに出かける

thanks for the responds

Answer (score 2):

行く means "go", 出る means "leave, depart" and 出かける means "leave this place for some errand to do elsewhere".

So 川へせんたくしに行く and 川へせんたくに出かける (as well as 川へせんたくしに出かける) make hardly any difference, but you wouldn't be likely to say 地獄{じごく}へ出かける unless you're something like "[underworld detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YuYu_Hakusho)".

Comment: Is 「川へ洗濯***に***出かける」 correct or did you mean 「川へ洗濯***しに***出かける」? If you didn't make a typo could you explain why the former is correct? (The other two examples you gave use ***しに*** so I'm a little confused.)

Comment: Both are correct. it's kind of hard to explain in English, but like "for washing" and "to do his wash", maybe? (And 川へ**せんたくに**行く is good as well.)

Comment: Ah, an English explanation wasn't necessary. Just saying 「洗濯に行く 」 was also valid was enough for the light bulb to go off in my head. Thanks.

Comment: @Pandacoder https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/when-does-a-suru-noun-require-%E3%81%97-in-front-of-a-purposive-%E3%81%AB