# Can a noun with adverbial particle に be used to express "going somewhere with a purpose"?

Tags: particle-に

I am familiar with the formula: 連用形+に+動の動詞　(行く、来る、帰る、戻る、出かける、出る) which means "moving somewhere with a purpose", where "moving" is a template for going, coming, returning, etc.

E.g.

> 林さんは何をしに来たのですか。Why did Hayashi come?
>
> 本を借りに来たんです。He came to borrow a book.

Can a noun+に be used in the same manner to express purpose?

E.g. can 健診に be used as the purpose for the verb いく?

> 林さんは**健診に**病院に行った。Hayashi went to the hospital for medical examination.

Comment: Sure, it's same to "for" and "to".

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5134/9831

Answer (score 2):

The [google dictionary](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=6TgkWeXoEYi98QXN_4qoCw) that popped up from my google search has 7 definitions. Number 1 seems to be the most relevant to your question.

The part which relates to purpose is as follows:

> 動詞が表す動作・作用が向かう対象を示す。「山―登る」
>
> 《移動に関する動詞と共に使って》 動作・作用による到達点を示す。
>    「京都―着く」*[1st]*...
>
> 動作・作用の目的とする、もの・ことを示す。「頭痛―きく薬」*[2nd]*...

As far as purpose is concerned, に can be used with a verb related to movement to show destination or what is attained (1st). (Sorry; my translation is very rough). In addition, it can show the purpose of a verb's action or operation (2nd).

The last example sentence reads: "a medicine that is effective for headaches." Here the に is clearly used to express purpose.

Hope this helps.