# Why is に used in 料理によく使います?

Tags: particle-に

> **この野菜{やさい}はきれいな赤い色をしているので、料理{りょうり}によく使います。**

why using  に in this phrase

> 料理**に**よく使います

Comment: What particle do you think is appropriate for?

Comment: I think you should see 'ni' here as for 'in the cooking', or 'in the domain of cooking', which also implies a physical position particle in English.

Answer (score 3):

に has many functions, but in this case it marks a purpose of the verb, like English "for". 料理に使う means "use (it) for cooking".

Related:

- [に行く grammar with 行く replaced by other verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52693/5010)
- [When are へ and に used together?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5125/5010)
- [Is it true that only movement verbs can take [V-stem]に to express a purpose?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2957/5010)
- [Can a noun with adverbial particle に be used to express "going somewhere with a purpose"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47635/5010)
- [When does a suru-noun require し in front of a purposive-に?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5134/5010)