# In which word form does 探し belong to?

Tags: conjugations, renyōkei, verbs-of-motion

I confuse with usage of 探し in this sentence:

> 探しに行くんだ そこへ

I have tried to google it. But they show me 探す which is a u-verb. And I am unable to find *sagashi*. The closest one is *sagashita* which is its past form. It is a type of clipping such as "chemistry" becomes "chem" or what?

My question is: in what form *sagashi* is and when to use it?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2957/9831

Comment: So how come sagasu change into sagashi? It is because sagashi is the gerund of sagasu? Or because there is particle に after sagasu? So basically 探しに行く means "to go to looking for"?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it means, in the spirit of the question chocolate quoted, it means 'going in order to search', which is basically to go look for. Dictionary link: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%8E%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%AB

Comment: Why 探す changed into 探し?

Comment: @Husain Do you know verb stem, which is also known as "masu-stem", "pre-masu form", "continuative form" or 連用形? 探し is simply the stem of 探す. One way to understand it is that [stem works like a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010) and the particle に takes a noun before it. In English, you can say "for finding it" but not "for find it".