# Which grammar structure does this sentence fit into?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

Which grammar structure does the following sentence fit into?

> あのナイフは、パンを切るのにつかいます。

I translated it as "That knife is used to cut bread". However, I can't understand the 切るのにつかいます part. The closest I got was that you can use に ＋ V ます to express purpose, such as 勉強しに来ました(I came to study). But these examples did not use the nominalizer. What structure is used in this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2963/9831 -- "[Verb in 連用形 + に] can **only** be used with motion verbs such as 行く, 来る, 帰る, 入る, 出る...

Comment: The 切るの in your sentence is simply a different way of saying 切る事. It is thus the noun form of the verb, just as cut -> cutting. They are not always interchangable, for extensive details see here: https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/nominalizers-koto-and-no/