# what does しにみえてる mean?

Tags: grammar

The phrase in question is: 広瀬さんが指導碁をお願いしにみえてるんだけど

In context, I think it means something like "Hirose-san came to ask for a teaching game, but..." but I still have not been able to break down my understanding of this phrase to my own satisfaction.

It is the form しにみえてる that I am stuck on. As I understand it, [にみえる](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-ni-mieru/) usually means that something appears a certain way (appears to be asking for a teaching game?), but in that case then I would expect the form て見える or ように見える when attached to a verb, I have not been able to find this form of 連用形 + に見える。

I also understand that v1連用形 + に + v2 means to do v2 for the purpose of v1, for example 見に行く means to go see something. [But it seems this only applies to movement verbs like 行く and 見える is not such a verb.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2957/is-it-true-that-only-movement-verbs-can-take-v-stem%E3%81%AB-to-express-a-purpose?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I also thought of てみる (trying to ask for a teaching game?) but I don't think that makes sense here either and anyway there is no て form.

Thanks again for all your help.

[image: 広瀬さんが指導碁をお願いしにみえてるんだけど あ、ムリにとは]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This 見える is an honorific version of (訪ねて)来る. You can think of it as a slightly less polite variant of お見えになる.

> #### [み・える【見える】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210883/meaning/m0u/)
>
> ［動ア下一］［文］み・ゆ［ヤ下二］
>
> ５ 「来る」の尊敬語。おいでになる。いらっしゃる。「先生が―・えました」

Thus, this 見える *is* a movement verb, and the grammar of 見に行く applies in this case, too.

Comment: Thank you! I never would have thought of this