Is it possible that you can do this or is it because it’s a song and all grammatical logic is thrown out?

I don’t think Lemon needs any explanation, literally if you’ve ever heard of any Japanese song, you’ll come across this.
So what’s the deal with this を, I know it marks the direct object but we need a transitive or 他動詞 to be exact to do it and is the 取り here doing the job here? I know that shifting it into the verb stems makes it connecter like the て form but if that’s the case then we should be able to put に after 取り, に particle like が、を、で、へ needs to be connected to a noun. I do know that when shifting it to the verb stem it makes the verb into its true noun form and you put に after the verb stem of the verb to indicate the ultimate goal (meaning your goal is to do the verb that has に attached to it) but if that’s the case then を isn’t doing it’s job cause there’s no transitive verb(他動詞) for it. Either 取り is the て form but in this doesn’t make any sense why に can be attached to it since it can only attach to nouns or consider 取り as the noun version but in turn makes を completely meaningless.
I’m familiar with CureDolly’s explanation and I’ve watched the い stem video of verbs and do know that it can be the て　form and the true noun form of the verb but can you simultaneously use it as a て form and a noun at the same time cuz it seems like it’s using both at the same time.

This question is similar to: に行く grammar with 行く replaced by other verbs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2956 . (i-stem)に(dictionary form) is a common construction.

This is a specialised use of the i-stem along with に to indicate "purpose of motion". The simplest verb of motion to use as an example is 行く:

Vに行く = go (somewhere) to do <verb>

In the case where that first verb is transitive, you can include its object in the syntax:

[OをV]に行く

The Oを part here binds to V, and the whole OをV subclause indicates what you're going to do. So, in your example:

忘れ物を取りに帰る
"go back to pick up something I forgot"

取り here is neither a noun nor equivalent to the て-form. It's just part of the expression's syntax; just part of how the ～に行く (or in this case 帰る) construction is formed.

The i-stem of a verb can be considered noun-like in terms of how it works grammatically - and the て-form is really just an i-stem plus て, with a sound shift. They're comparable to gerunds and gerundives in English, in my analysis.

Right, but to be clear, in this construction it cannot be said to function nominally (since it accepts objects), nor is it replaceable with the て form. That was meant to be the scope of my claim.
