# Verb after な-adjective, is it necessary to complete the sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, na-adjectives

I read [somewhere](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13127/why-does-%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-use-%E3%81%AA/13145#13145) that 形容動詞 are a special subclass of nouns. Contrarily 形容詞, the い adjectives, are actually a lot more similar to verbs. During the time that I have been learning Japanese language (almost a year) I have developed the notion that verb is an essential part of a complete sentence and な-adjective can not fullfill the duty of the verb. Yet, In [The essence of sentence construction](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/blog/2009/05/18/the-essence-of-sentence-construction/) on Tae Kim's Blog, the part about **Treating verb phrases as nouns**, in order to make a sentence, な-adjective is used as a substitute for verb and だ comes after that only "If you don’t want to sound girly". In this example on Tae Kim's Blog

> たくさん運動するのはいいが、**ちゃんと休むのも大切。**

is being treated as a complete sentence and then we read:

> Finally, let’s add a bit of motherly advice-sounding nuance to it and give it a more conversation style, since it sounds like the speaker is trying to admonish the listener.
>
> たくさん運動するのはいいけど、ちゃんと休むのも大切よ。
>
> If you don’t want to sound girly, you’ll want to add 「だ」 when using 「よ」 with nouns/na-adjectives.
>
> たくさん運動するのはいいけど、ちゃんと休むのも大切だよ。

My question is that, in order to make a complete sentence , 大切 being a な-adjective, **why it is not necessary** for a verb to come after it?

Comment: I don't think there's any answer to this other than simply "the rule you learned is incorrect, and a sentence in Japanese does not have to end in a verb."

Comment: 'だ comes after that only "If you don’t want to sound girly"' - that advice is purely for the use of よ.

Comment: Answering to this question is close to creation of your own grammar theory. You can think whatever, but that doesn't seem really substantial anyway.

Comment: @user4092 Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question but I don't think a verb is always necessary after なadjective. In this case, you can think of it that there is a be-verb and sometimes the be-verb is hidden.

This sentence is omitting the be-verb and it means "It's good to exercise a lot but taking a break is also important".

> たくさん運動するのはいいが、ちゃんと休むのも大切。

The be-verb for this sentence could be

> たくさん運動するのはいいが、ちゃんと休むのも大切**です**。(formal)

or

> たくさん運動するのはいいが、ちゃんと休むのも大切**だ**。(casual)

The `よ` is just a post positional particle, not a verb. You can look up 終助詞 for more explanation on this. In short, it kind of adds a little more nuances to the sentence.

Comment: Downvoter, it's always nice to give an explanation for a down-vote.